# Non Conducting riser/bushing for in floor recessed electrical outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle, floor

I replaced some flooring that now has a different height that previous and so the receptacles look even more "RECESSED" than previously. It looks like from one of the receptacles (see pic, sorry for not a great image). That there is a coiled piece of wire or some other plastic device to rise the outlet up. Need a little more "lift". Anybody know if there is a specific part for this and where to get it? I can MacGyver it but...[image]
[image]

Comment: Sideways to your question, if it was me, I'd replace with a tamper resistant duplex receptacle, to help keep dust away from the contacts.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are [Plastic wall plate spacers.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Gardner-Bender-24-Pack-0-75-in-W-x-4-in-L-Yellow-Plastic-Wall-Plate-Spacer/4573784?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-elc-_-ggl-_-LIA_ELC_106_Tools-Wire-Connectors-_-4573784-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2eilBhCCARIsAG0Pf8vn8dq72f55n9oT1FyBgYcOzOFxyvvocPX--wOj40cRXKPd673hO_4aAkeLEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

The name is a bit misleading. They space out the outlet or switch, not the wall plate.

Tear one off the strip and bend it over. They also can be stacked. Aline the slots and they can be added without taking the screws all the way out if you don't need too many.

If you do need longer screws you will need to purchase them separately.

Comment: Helpful. It looks like someone took a piece of #10 insulated wire and wound them like a coil around a screw/nail to create the initial spacer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a box entender at this location to raise the outlet. You've got too much space between the finished floor and the outlet. You can pick one up at your home store.